# change email sender address in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, gmail

I have a web application built with CodeIgniter 3. Tank auth is used as authentication layer. Emails will be sent to users based on accounts created and other triggers. I do not want users see my actual from email address but `noreply@example.com`.

I use Gmail SMTP configurations:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxx';
```

And here is my testing mail function:

```
$from = $reply_to = 'noreply@example.com';
$subject = lang('test_send_email_subject');

$this->config->load('email', TRUE);
$email_config = $this->config->item('email');
$this->load->library('email', $email_config);

$this->email->from($from, 'example');
$this->email->reply_to($reply_to, 'example');
$this->email->to($to);

$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message(lang('test_send_email_message'));

$result = $this->email->send(FALSE);
$this->session->set_flashdata('debugger_result', $this->email->print_debugger());
```

The debugger result I got is actually correctly showing from email address as noreply@example.com, which is what I set in codes:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP i192sm2099289lfb.14 - gsmtp 
hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [89.166.7.101]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
from: 250 2.1.0 OK i192sm2099289lfb.14 - gsmtp
to: 250 2.1.5 OK i192sm2099289lfb.14 - gsmtp
data: 354  Go ahead i192sm2099289lfb.14 - gsmtp
250 2.0.0 OK 1454662672 i192sm2099289lfb.14 - gsmtp 
quit: 221 2.0.0 closing connection i192sm2099289lfb.14 - gsmtp
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: smtp
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Fri, 5 Feb 2016 16:57:50 +0800
From: "example" <noreply@example.com>
Return-Path: <noreply@example.com>
Reply-To: "example" <noreply@example.com>
To: xxx@example.com
Subject: Test Email
X-Sender: noreply@example.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <56b4640e47745@example.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_56b4640e4776b"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_56b4640e4776b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is a test email, nice to know it works.


--B_ALT_56b4640e4776b
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is a test email, nice to know it works.

--B_ALT_56b4640e4776b--
```

However, the email I received is not:

[image: Email sent via CodeIgniter]

Please help, thank you.

Comment: This could be not the problem on you side. It is possible that mail client ignores fake 'From' and still show actual email. So just use new email box, which you are ready to show to users.

Comment: @sphinks, what do you mean by saying "use new email box, which you are ready to show to users"?

Comment: you said "I do not want users see my actual from email address", so I offer you to create new email box, which you can show to you users as is, without overriding it.

Comment: aha..., but that is not what I want. I want people to see `noreplay@example.com` only, if that is possible.

Comment: as far as I know not all email clients will consume this value. So it is possible that you code is working ok.